# StateHasChanged not execute on async call Blazor Server App

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

When the user press on a specific button i need to show an animation inside the button and disable it ( the method called need several seconds to accompish).
This is my html:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                @if (IsDownloading)
                {
                    <button class="btn btn-primary float-right search disabled" disabled><span class='fa-left fas fa-sync-alt spinning'></span>Downloading...</button>
                }
                else
                {
                    <button id="REC_PDF" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(()=>getPDF())">Download Labels</button>
                }
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this is my code:

```
protected bool IsDownloading { get; set; }

public async Task getPDF()
{
    IsDownloading = true;
    StateHasChanged();

    await generate_pdf(labels);

    IsDownloading = false;
    StateHasChanged();
}

private async Task generate_pdf(List<Tuple<string, string, string, string>> filtered_label)
{
    loading = true;
    string PDF_PATH = "./PDF/" + CurrentValue;
    foreach (Tuple<string,string,string,string> label in filtered_label)
    {

        if (!Directory.Exists(PDF_PATH))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(PDF_PATH);
        }
.......
```

The code is working but the rendering of the page called by StateHasChanged(); is executed 2 times when the method getPDF ( and generate_PDF consequentially) is fully executed.

I need page rendering on the frist call to show css loading animation.

( as suggested in other post i have used InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged()); but is not working)

Thanks.

Comment: `@onclick="@(()=>getPDF())"` <-- Why? By removing all task information and thus not awaiting anything. `@onclick="getPDF"` is the right way... but not the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The click event is handled like this in Blazor:

```
var task = InvokeAsync(EventMethod);
StateHasChanged();
if (!task.IsCompleted)
{
    await task;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Note `StateHasChanged` doesn't actually re-render the component, it just stacks a `RenderFragment` delegate on the Render queue.

All the code runs on the UI Synchronisation context, so the render event queued by calling `StateHasChanged` only gets executed either:

- at the point the Event Method yields control
- if no yield takes place (because there's only sync code inside the Task block) at the end.

I can't see any code that yields in your `generate_pdf`.

Try the following:

```
public async Task getPDF()
{
    IsDownloading = true;
    await Task.Yield();

    await generate_pdf(labels);

    IsDownloading = false;
}
```

Note: `Directory.CreateDirectory` is not an async method.  Only `FileStream` has async methods.

Comment: Ok I get it. This is an implementation on a working app so i was tring to implemente this feature w/o re-write the method structure. Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. After 2 days of trying many different approaches, YIELD was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `generate_pdf()` is not asynchronous. Adding `async` is not enough. You need something asynchronous to enable a Render.

Since this is a UI problem I suggest to solve it in the top layer:

```
public async Task getPDF()
{
    IsDownloading = true;
    //StateHasChanged();  // not needed at start
    await task.Delay(1);  // allow the UI to update    

    try
    {
      await generate_pdf(labels);     
    }
    finally
    {
      IsDownloading = false;         
    }
    //StateHasChanged();  // not needed at the end
}
```

When  generate_pdf() does not do any `await` itself you might as well make it a normal void method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this modifications:

```
public async Task getPDF()
{
    if (IsDownloading) return;

    IsDownloading = true;
    StateHasChanged();

    await generate_pdf(labels);
}
```

then at the end of `generate_pdf` (better inside a try/finally block) add:

```
    IsDownloading = false;
    StateHasChanged();
```